# jqtouch - no loading image appears

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I'm creating a web app using jqtouch and have an ajax link to an external html page. The link works fine when there is internet connectivity, but when the connection is not available, there is no "loading" message.

Should this be a default behavior in jqtouch? If so, what could be causing the image to NOT display?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you post some sample code to clarify?

Comment: This code is used in a an unordered list with the "rounded" class:
<li class="arrow"><a href="http://www.career.uga.edu/mobilewebapp/ccajaxevents.html">Upcoming Events</a></li>
I need a "loading" animation to play over the screen while the external page is being loaded. The "loading.gif" image is being preloaded in the script on the page, but I don't know how to make it display when the link is tapped.

On a related note, I need to display a notification that a network connection is needed to access the link (if no connection is present). Is this a feature of jqtouch?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Well I done it by my own.

JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#link').tap( function(e){
        $('#myloading').css("display","");
        window.location = this.href;
        return false;
    });
    $('#myloading').center();
});
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}
```

And put a div on the page:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="myloading">
    <img src="/css/jqtouch/apple/img/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
```

And all external links like:

```
<a id="link" href="page.html">My links</a>
```

Conclusion:

I convert all links to be worked on tap event.

I hope it solves your problem.